# Type hint for returning loguru logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Does anyone know the proper type hint for returning a loguru logger? Using `loguru.Logger` passes mypy checks, but when the function `get_logger` is called I get the error `AttributeError: module 'loguru' has no attribute 'Logger'`

```
import copy
from pathlib import Path
from sys import stdout

from loguru import logger
import loguru


def get_logger(log_path: Path) -> loguru.Logger:
    logger.remove()
    logger_ = copy.deepcopy(logger)
    logger_.add(stdout)
    logger_.add(f"{log_path}.log")

    return logger_
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learned that `loguru.Logger` is correct and can be used without throwing an error if `from __future__ import annotations` is added to the list of imports.

This comes from the [loguru type hint documentation](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/type_hints.html)

Example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import loguru

def get_logger(
    colorize: bool = True,
    serialize: bool = False,
    file_format: str = LOG_FORMAT_SIMPLE,
) -> loguru.Logger:
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411281/11277611) answer but failed, well I solved it by

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from loguru import Logger
```

Comment: I tried both, neither worked for me. I am on Python 3.8.